# Show loading placeholder while slow component is rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component which renders slowly on mobile devices (data is already fetched, the problem is in slow render method). Need to show loading placeholder while it renders.

My naive approach was to wrap *SlowComponent* with parent component *Loader* which shows both *Spinner* and *SlowComponent* until *SlowComponent* mounts. Then hide *Spinner*. This approach failed because parent component will not render until all of its children are rendered (I guess), so *Spinner* is never shown.

Comment: Have you tried to use onLayout event?

Comment: This honestly smells like a misuse of the react hooks.  I've pushed react to some pretty outstanding limits and it's still rendered just fine.  But if you are running data manipulation within your render method, that could easily cause a delay.  If that's the case, instead of looking for how to show a loading message, you should focus on figuring out how to separate out your data manipulation concerns to run before the render method is invoked.

Comment: @Bünyamin Benny Genel I didn't. This is react-native specific, right? Can't use it in such case

Comment: @gravityplanx I have svg which is generated from json which can be pretty big. Besides optimizing generation process (I agree that it can be optimized even more but everything has its limits) can you suggest an approach? I'm thinking of 1) wrapping svg generation inside promise; 2)setState on promise resolve; 3)render from state; But I have a bunch of components like this and wan't to find reusable solution (like Loader parent component)  for all of them.

Comment: That is actually exactly what you can do. Converting the time consuming process to a Promise and running a function after all the process finished is the way to go I think.

Comment: But there is a problem: SlowComponent doesn't do everything by itself. It delegates job to its children components. If I put code inside promise, children components will not execute their render methods.  Looks like I need to extract everything I can to promise and make renders as light as possible.